# Bind9 zone files

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Well for the better part of the last two hours I've tried to figure out what is actually wrong, but I can't seem to find anything obvious to me.

What I'm trying to do is setup my DNS for say(per example) domain.com.
This should include two NS records, namely ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com.
With that there should be a mail record, as well as a CNAME record for www.

I've been trough roughly 20 how to's in the last two hours, rewrote everything from scratch four times and I still can't seem to find whats wrong.
My only suspicion to this might be two things; the error I get from the bind9 daemon when I stop the service, and the named.conf file.

The error I get from the bind9 daemon when stopping the service is:

```
* Stopping domain name service... bind9                                        rndc: connection to remote host closed
This may indicate that
* the remote server is using an older version of the command protocol,
* this host is not authorized to connect,
* the clocks are not syncronized, or
* the key is invalid.
```

I honestly doesn't know what this means, apart from the key defined in /etc/bind/rndc.key that's not in the named.conf file(yes, I did try to add it to no avail).

Here's all the zone files, and configuration files; http://208.77.101.5/bind9/

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop bind, the scripts use `rndc stop` command. Check if you run it by hands if you have the same answer. If it is the case, check
`netstat -pnlt | grep 953` if bind is waiting for your connections
check if your keys in /etc/bind/rndc.key are the same in /etc/bind/named.conf

If you change the keys, you must kill the process as it will not be stopped by rndc, and then restart bind

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN      11524/named
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      11524/named


There are no keys defined in /etc/bind/named.conf?

Comment: Do you use a bind version 9 ? Do you have the section key "rndc-key" {
      algorithm hmac-md5;
      secret "ddddd==";
};
somewhere ?

Comment: I added it, and rndc-confgen confirms the key in both files.

Comment: Do you kill the process to reload the key in bind ?

Comment: yes, but somehow It's been fixed.
Although, I won't know if the DNS is actually working until it updates.

But by using dig all NS, A, MX CNAME records seems to respond fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error appeared to me during master-slave synchronization, and the problem was in different time of those machines. Try to `ntpdate` some timeserver.

Comment: "12 May 11:49:45 ntpdate[26410]: step-systime: Operation not permitted"
so that's a no-go.

Comment: got ntpdate working, but the error still does not go away.

Comment: Try run it as root. Or use another tool to set time on machines. Time cannot be much different.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote previous message too long. It's not time problem then.

Answer (score 0):

My `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` contains the following …

```
include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";

controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 allow {
        localhost;
    }

    keys {
        rndc-key;
    };
};
```

As far as I remember, this tells `bind` to allow `rndc` connections from the localhost using the key defined in `/etc/bind/rndc.key`.

As root, you might try executing

```
# rndc -V status
```

to get `rndc` debugging messages which may help you diagnose why `rndc` is failing to connect to `bind`.